# Communicating between Apache and a different process

Tags: apache, sockets

I want to communicate between Apache and an external process. 
I can modify the source of the process (written in C++) as much as I want, but Apache should (hopefully) remain the same. I was thinking about just using an Intranet socket between PHP and the program, but that just seems inefficient and hard to do if there are multiple page loads at once, and using a file is even worse.

Essentially, Apache (and PHP) would query the external program, and should read or modify a hashtable. How should I go about doing this?

Comment: Is this from php or apache? Apache isn't going to 'communicate' with anything unless you're reverse-proxying or writing an apache module.

Comment: Well, I suppose I would have to use PHP.

Comment: You don't have to use php. It could be an apache module; it could be some non-shitty programming language (i.e. not php).

Comment: I guess I could use a module, though, I've never written one before. If I use a module, then how would I go about approaching it?

Comment: @Ralph Wiggum I got a similar problem these days, how did you resolve yours?

Comment: @MartinSchlott I don't remember, but I think I just added an HTTP server into my 2nd process. You could just use a TCP socket from PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Make your 'external process' expose an HTTP server, then reverse-proxy from apache to that HTTP server. Done.

Comment: I was thinking about that, but 1) it would cause more load on an already extremely loaded application, and 2) I would have to integrate an HTTP server into it (which seems like a bit of work, and I'm quite lazy)... so I'll stick this as a maybe for now...

Comment: re: 1) which application are you talking about? 2) what kind of long-running daemon doesn't already have an event loop?? this is a trivial thing e.g. with twisted in python.

Comment: It's hard to explain, but it's a bit of a concept application. It just has this resource intensive loop that does lookups from a datastructure in memory.